# Table join; select 1 entry from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have two tables. One "main" table with all the data and a unique `id` per entry. The other table is an audit log, where that `id` from main will be stored multiple times in the audit table.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    a.title, a.id, a.name, t.user, t.time  
FROM 
    MainTable a      
INNER JOIN 
    AuditLog AS t ON a.id = t.id    
WHERE 
    a.NAME LIKE 'Something%'  
    AND a.ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

Which gives a result like:

```
TITLE           ID          NAME         USER          TIME
----------------------------------------------------------------
Something1      someth1     Some 1       User5         468534771
Something1      someth1     Some 1       User7         468574887
Something2      someth2     Some 2       User6         468584792
```

Which returns multiple results of the ID. I only want the oldest (from `AuditLog`) entry and not every one. So the result I would want looks like:

```
TITLE           ID          NAME         USER          TIME
----------------------------------------------------------------
Something1      someth1     Some 1       User5         468534771
Something2      someth2     Some 2       User6         468584792
```

How can this be done? I'm trying some subqueries within the join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sql server 2005+, you can use `row_number()`

```
select title, id, name, user, time
from
(
  SELECT a.title, a.id, a.name, t.user, t.time,
    row_number() over(partition by a.id order by t.time) rn
  FROM MainTable a
  INNER JOIN AuditLog AS t
    ON a.id = t.id
  WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Something%'
    AND a.ACTIVE='Y'
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eef6c/4)

Or you can use a sub-query to get the min time:

```
SELECT a.title, a.id, a.name, l.user, l.time
FROM MainTable a 
INNER JOIN AuditLog l
  ON a.id = l.id
INNER JOIN
(
  select min(time) Mintime, id
  from AuditLog
  group by id
) AS t 
  ON l.id = t.id
  AND l.time = t.mintime
WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Something%' 
  AND a.ACTIVE='Y';
```

Comment: No need for these subquery shenanigans. ORDER BY with TOP 1 fits the bill and should be fastest to run, depending on table indexes, etc.

Comment: @saarp: Like in User Smith's answer? Or like in Andomar's?

Comment: @saarp did you even read the question?  An ORDER BY TOP 1 will return one record which is not what they want. They want one record for each unique id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.title, a.id, a.name, t.user, t.time
FROM MainTable a
INNER JOIN AuditLog AS t
ON a.id = t.id
WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Something%'
AND a.ACTIVE='Y'
ORDER BY T.DATE DESC
```

Comment: The `like` suggests that more than one MainTable record might be matched

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outer apply`, like:

```
select  *
from    MainTable a
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    AuditLog t
        where   a.id = t.id
        order by
                t.time
        ) t
where   a.name like 'Something%'
        and a.active = 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
SELECT a.title, a.id, a.name, t.user, t.time  
FROM MainTable a      
    JOIN AuditLog AS t ON a.id = t.id
        JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(TIME) AS LASTTIME FROM AUDITLOG) AS c 
        ON c.ID =  t.id AND c.LASTTIME = t.time    
WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Something%'  
    AND a.ACTIVE = 'Y'
```